# Изменить цвет у части текста и сделать её кликабельной у TextView

Tags: android, строки, textview, color, spannable

Есть строка. Часть этой строки (с 55 по 83 символы) я хочу сделать кликабельным и поменять цвет на другой.
Дело в том, что кликабельным это часть стала, но цвет не поменяла. (если менять таким же способом цвет в другом месте, то цвет поменяется)

Может быть какой-то приоритет есть или что?

Вопрос: как мне поменять цвет и сделать кликабельным часть строки?

```
    TextView userOk = view.findViewById(R.id.user_ok);

    SpannableString ss = new SpannableString(App.getContext().getString(R.string.user_ok));
    ClickableSpan clickableSpan = new ClickableSpan() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View textView) {
            Toast.makeText(App.getContext(),"ds",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    };

    ss.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.BLACK), 55, 83, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    ss.setSpan(clickableSpan, 55, 83, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

    userOk.setText(ss);
    userOk.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

Comment: Попробуйте сначала установить `ClickableSpan`, а потом `ForegroundColorSpan`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно переопределить метод `updateDrawState()` у класса `ClickableSpan`, в котором указать нужный цвет для кликабельного текста. Таким образом можно будет обойтись только одним `ClickableSpan`. И тогда `ForegroundColorSpan` становится не нужен:

```
ClickableSpan clickableSpan = new ClickableSpan() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View textView) {
        Toast.makeText(App.getContext(),"ds",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void updateDrawState(TextPaint ds) {
        ds.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    }
};
```